Apexcharts plot point does not coincide with the xaxis label ticks. Tick is places slightly behind

As you can see in the image the tooltip and plot graph are ahead of the x-axis label. How do we align them together?
here is my base config
export const baseChartConfig = (): ApexOptions => {
  return {
    xaxis: {
      tickPlacement: 'between',
      tickAmount: 12,
      labels: {
        offsetX: 10,
        trim: true,
        hideOverlappingLabels: true,
        style: {
          fontSize: '11px'
        }
      }
    },
    yaxis: {
      labels: {
        offsetY: -5,
        style: {
          fontSize: '11px'
        },
        formatter: (value: number) => value.toFixed(0)
      },
      forceNiceScale: true,
      min: 0,
      max: (largestValue: number) => largestValue + 1
    },
    grid: {
      show: true,
      borderColor: 'var(--va-light-tertiary)',
      position: 'back',
      strokeDashArray: 3,
      padding: {
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 10,
        left: 10
      },
      xaxis: {
        lines: {
          show: true
        }
      },
      yaxis: {
        lines: {
          show: true
        }
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        columnWidth: '25%',
        borderRadius: 1
      }
    },
  }
}


I have tried removing the padding, offset, etc., but nothing seems to make a difference. This problem persists even if I zoom in or zoom out of the chart.
